# How to "roll" up a PHP array of unknown depth?

Tags: php, recursion

I'm not sure what the proper term for what I'm trying to accomplish is, but if I have an array structure like this:

```
[
  'owner' => 'Fred',
  'cars' => [
    0 =>  [
     'model' => 'Toyota',
     'passengers' => [
         0 => [
          'name' => "Tom",
          'age' => 35,
          'hobbies' => [
            0 => [
              'name' => 'Chess',
              'exp' => 'Master'
            ],
            1 => [
              'name' => 'Soccer',
              'exp' => 'Novice'
            ]
           ]
         ],
         1 => [
          'name' => "Bill", 
          'age' => 30,
          'hobbies' => [
            0 => [
              'name' => 'Basketball',
              'exp' => 'Novice'
            ],
            1 => [
              'name' => 'Football',
              'exp' => 'Expert'
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
   ]
 ]
```

I want to be able to do nested replacements in a template based on the key.  So for this example I will have 3 templates, "cars", "passengers" and "hobbies".

## cars.txt

```
Model: <<model>> Passengers: <<passengers>>
```

## passengers.txt

```
<<name>> (<<age>>), <<hobbies>>;
```

## hobbies.txt

```
<<hobby>> - <<exp>>,
```

So I want to "roll" the array up into eventually just being:

```
[
  'owner' => 'Fred',
  'cars' => [
     0 => "Model: Toyota, Passengers: Tom (37) Chess - Master, Soccer - Novice; Bill (30) Basketball - Novice, Football - Expert;"
   ]
]
```

I'm just struggling on how to walk to the deepest leaf first to roll it up from the outside in since the replacements nest.

How can I do this?

Comment: Iterate over arrays with one of [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Comment: `EDIT:

I figured it out finally:` - then instead of editing your question. post this as regular answer and accept it to close the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally:

```
function normalizeTemplateVars($vars,$templates) {
  $expand_vars = function($parent_key,$parent_value) use($vars,$templates,&$expand_vars) {
    if(!is_array($parent_value)) return $parent_value;

    $tmp = [];
    foreach($parent_value as $item_index => $item_value) {
      foreach($item_value as $k => $v) $parent_value[$item_index][$k] = $expand_vars($k,$v);

      //mergeAndPurge just replaces variables in template
      $tmp[] = mergeAndPurge($parent_value[$item_index],$templates[$parent_key]);
    }

    return implode($tmp,PHP_EOL);      
  };

  $ret = [];
  foreach($vars as $k => $v) $ret[$k] = $expand_vars($k,$v);

  return $ret;
}

$replacement_vars = normalizeTemplateVars($vars, ['cars' => '<<owner>> <<cars>>','passengers' => '<<name>> (<<age), <<hobbies>>', 'hobbies' => '<<name>> - <<exp>>']);
```

This will return a 1-level deep array with just "cars" and "owner" which is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [iterate](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) over each of your embedded arrays, in order to build the `cars` string. In the example underneath, I used [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to build strings from the `passengers` and `hobbies` arrays :

```
<?php

$array = array(
    'owner' => 'Fred',
    'cars' => array(
        0 =>  array(
            'model' => 'Toyota',
            'passengers' => array(
                0 => array(
                    'name' => "Tom",
                    'age' => 35,
                    'hobbies' => array(
                        0 => array(
                            'name' => 'Chess',
                            'exp' => 'Master'
                        ),
                        1 => array(
                            'name' => 'Soccer',
                            'exp' => 'Novice'
                        )
                    )
                ),
                1 => array(
                    'name' => "Bill", 
                    'age' => 30,
                    'hobbies' => array(
                        0 => array(
                            'name' => 'Basketball',
                            'exp' => 'Novice'
                        ),
                        1 => array(
                            'name' => 'Football',
                            'exp' => 'Expert'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

$output = array('owner' => '', 'cars' => array());
$output['owner'] = $array['owner'];
foreach ($array['cars'] as $car) {
    $output_car = '';
    $output_passengers = array();
    foreach ($car['passengers'] as $passenger) {
        $output_hobbies = array();
        foreach ($passenger['hobbies'] as $hobby) {
            $output_hobbies[] = $hobby['name'] . ' - ' . $hobby['exp'];
        }
        $output_passengers[] = $passenger['name'] . ' (' . $passenger['age'] . ') ' . implode(', ', $output_hobbies);
    }
    $output_car = 'Model: ' . $car['model'] . ', Passengers: ' . implode('; ', $output_passengers);
    $output['cars'][] = $output_car;
}

var_dump($output);
```

It will output :

```
array (size=2)
  'owner' => string 'Fred' (length=4)
  'cars' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Model: Toyota, Passengers: Tom (35) Chess - Master, Soccer - Novice; Bill (30) Basketball - Novice, Football - Expert' (length=117)
```

I'm not that familiar with [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), but I bet the solution could be simpler (or at least lighter) with them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm looking for more of a general approach though.  I have a set of templates with names that correspond to the keys they need to be rendered against for each item.  I was hoping to find a good way to walk to the end of the tree, then come back up and render each key so that it could then be used as a replacement by the parent later.

So like when you were done with hobbies for the first passenger, you'd be left with an array like:

'hobbies' => "//rendered string"

Now I'd be able to use <<hobbies>> in the passengers template, then on up to cars.txt w/ passengers.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$data = [
    ['owner' => 'Fred',
        'cars' => [
            0 => [
                'model' => 'Toyota',
                'passengers' => [
                    0 => [
                        'name' => "Tom",
                        'age' => 35,
                        'hobbies' => [
                            0 => [
                                'name' => 'Chess',
                                'exp' => 'Master'
                            ],
                            1 => [
                                'name' => 'Soccer',
                                'exp' => 'Novice'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    1 => [
                        'name' => "Bill",
                        'age' => 30,
                        'hobbies' => [
                            0 => [
                                'name' => 'Basketball',
                                'exp' => 'Novice'
                            ],
                            1 => [
                                'name' => 'Football',
                                'exp' => 'Expert'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$result = [];

foreach ($data as $d) {
    $record['owner'] = $d['owner'];
    foreach($d['cars'] as $car){
        $car_data = "Model: ".$car['model'].", Passengers: ";
        $passengers = '';
        foreach($car['passengers'] as $p){
            $passenger = $p['name']."(".$p['age'].") ";
            $i = 0;
            $len = count($p['hobbies']);
            $hobbies = '';
            foreach($p['hobbies'] as $h){
                $hobby = '';
                if ($i < $len - 1) {
                    $hobby = $h['name']." - ".$h['exp'].",";
                } else if ($i == $len - 1) {
                    $hobby = $h['name']." - ".$h['exp'];
                }
                $i++;
                $hobbies = $hobbies.$hobby." ";
            }
            $passenger = $passenger.$hobbies.";";
            $passengers = $passengers.$passenger." ";
        }
        $car_data = $car_data.$passengers;
    }
    $record['cars'][] = $car_data;
    $result[] = $record;
}
```

**The output of `print_r($result);`**

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [owner] => Fred [cars] => Array ( [0] => Model:
>   Toyota, Passengers: Tom(35) Chess - Master, Soccer - Novice ; Bill(30)
>   Basketball - Novice, Football - Expert ; ) ) )

Comment: You have a trailing `;` at the end of your `cars` element string : https://eval.in/724695. You should consider building arrays and using `implode` instead of building strings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was hoping for a more generalized approach though.  In my real usecase, I have a set of templates that correspond to keys in the replacement array.  If the particular entry is cars, we render each item against the cars.txt template and return that back.  Cars relies on <<passengers>> as a replacement...passengers, relies on <<hobbies>> as a replacement.  So I need to turn "hobbies" into a string by rendering it first...then I can render passengers...then passengers can be used in cars.txt